# Add fields to 'new' view in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I would like to add additional fields to the Rails Admin 'new' view for a specific model object, 'User'. These fields would not be attributes on the model itself but instead just fields that I would like users to be able to submit information with in order to calculate another field.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is definitely possible. Could you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: So I am currently creating new users via the Rails Admin tool. Right now that new view only shows fields for attributes of that model (fields on the table). I would like to add two additional fields to that view (the form). I then want to use those two fields to calculate a value for one of the actual attributes on the model. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Add virtual field to your model in rails admin using,

```
config.model Address do
  list do
    # virtual field
    configure :full_address do
      # any configuration
    end
    fields :full_address, :street, :number #, ...
  end
end
```

Reference - https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields#virtual-fields

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely familiar with Rails Admin, but you should be able to get what you want with Rails' virtual attributes mechanism.

In your `user.rb` model file, you need to add an `attr_accessor` line, listing the symbols you want to assign to your non-model fields, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :virtual_field_one, :virtual_field_two

  # Remainder of your code

end
```

You can add fields to the corresponding view that populate those values:

```
<%= f.text_field :virtual_field_one %>
```

Then you can add those attributes to the strong parameters method of your `users_controller.rb`, like this:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController

  # other code

  def user_params
    params.require(:activity).permit(:mode_field_one, :mode_field_two, :virtual_field_one, :virtual_field_two)
  end

  # other code

end
```

Now you should be able to access `virtual_field_one` and `virtual_field_two` from the `params` hash like any other field in your `User` model:

```
virtual_field_one = params[:virtual_field_one]
```